# Sentinel-2 clouds filtering in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, cloud-cover

I need to filter a Sentinel-2 image collection in order to have almost no clouds.
I used the following code:

```
//Dates of interest
var START = ee.Date('2017-03-28');
var FINISH = ee.Date('2020-07-31');    
//Merge different plot
var Plot = Plot01.merge(Plot02);

//Create ImageCollection    
var ImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection(S2L2A)    
.filterDate(START,FINISH)    
//Filter data by location    
.filterBounds(Plot)    
//Filter data based on metadata property -> cloudy pixel percentage <5%    
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 5)    
//Return clipped image    
.map(function(image){return image.clip(Plot)})
```

The filter of cloudy pixel percentage <5% refers to the entire Sentinel-2 tile. How can I perform this filtering process referring just to my Plot?

Comment: What do mean by the entire sentinel2 tile, I think you have already filtered the S2L2A collection with the bounds of your plot, so it will be filtering the collection images intersecting with the Plot.